# Doctrine DQL and Namespaces (relative only?)

Tags: doctrine, dql

i noticed that if i try to do soemthing like

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM \Application\Entities\User u');
```

i get

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near '\Application\Entities\User': Error: Class '\' is not defined.

if i do

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM Application\Entities\User u');
```

its ok. so the question is, can i say that DQL only accepts relative namespaces in DQL statements?

Comment: That looks like a bug. AFAIK Doctrine 2 isn't released yet, so you might want to report that to the developers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i found the answer at [doctrine forums](http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/71eccbab5303e9c5#)

> There are no "relative" namespaces in
>   strings
>
> It must be the fully qualified class
>   name minus the beginning \