# Short class names instead of full namespace and path in Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

With **doctrine2**, i created my `entities` in `Entities` folder.

Folder:

```
./
    HelloEntity.php
    WorldEntity.php
```

I created my structure in PHP and import them:

```
$namespaceYaml = array($connection->getBundle()->getNamespace() => $bundleFolder.'/Entity/ORM/');
$driver = new YamlDriver($namespaceYaml, '.orm.yml');
$path = $bundleFolder.'/Resource/config/doctrine/metadata/orm';
$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(array($path), true);
$config->setEntityNamespaces(array($connection->getBundle()->getName() => $connection->getBundle()->getNamespace().'\Entity'));
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
```

Now, it is working. I can use them.

For example:

```
$qb = $this->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('Hello'); //short here but long in from()
$qb->from('MyWeb\Entities\Hello', 'h'); //Hello Entity
```

Now, `MyWeb` is my main root/namespace. When i want to use doctrine with my tables, i have to write `MyWeb\Entities\Hello`. All i want to do is shorten them. Can't i **just** use `'Hello'`

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, i found the answer on somewhere else on StackOverflow. It is not the same question but looks like it answers both.

Shortly, We have to use fully qualified namespaces for table names instead of short one. But we can use short names when we get the repository (besides bundle name)

Refer: [Doctrine DQL and Namespaces (relative only?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327835/doctrine-dql-and-namespaces-relative-only)

Now, i found the answer.

**Answer**:

My previous solution is correct. We have to use fully qualified namespaces minus slash at the first str.

**But**, we can also use it by short.

**See**, every `entityManmager` has an `Repository` and we can get it by using `$em->getRepository()`. After that, with `createQueryBuilder('e')` (attention to "**e**" here) generates `HelloEntity` name itself and assign it to the `e` alias.

So, my code was wrong and no need to enter namespace :)

**Conclusion**:

Instead of this:

```
$qb = $this->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('Hello'); //short here but long in from()
$qb->from('MyWeb\Entities\Hello', 'h'); //Hello Entity
```

Use this:

```
$qb = $this->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('h'); //h assigned for Hello table and HelloEntity. So no need for from. It will fetch data two times then.
```

**Solved**.

Fix and idea came from: [Doctrine2 fetch 5 copy of each record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002981/doctrine2-fetch-5-copy-of-each-record)

Answer (score 3):

Never tried doctrine2 with pure php but this line looks like autoloader config:

```
$config->setEntityNamespaces(array($connection->getBundle()->getName() => $connection->getBundle()->getNamespace().'\Entity'));
```

Maybe if you use directory/namespace structure like MyWeb\ **Entity** \Hello it will work as you want

Comment: I am not sure if i understand correctly what you mean but i changed my structures to `MyWeb\Entity\Hello` but it did not helped :(